# SQL Server Management Studio v18.8

Tags: sql-server, service, connection, database-connection, ssms

I installed SQL server management studio 2020 now it’s not connecting
even I tried to start the SQL services but I didn’t find SQL services in services.

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you also installed  SQL Server? SSMS is just a client for SQL Server

Comment: The setup is 671.MB , is it complete setup or it’s just ssms ? Don’t know !

Comment: I am afraid, it is SSMS only.Set up file for SQL Server installation is about 1.5 GB

Comment: Just follow the guide provided by MS [SQL Server installation guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Maybe , thank you for you help! Exactly I just installed ssms